# How do you control caching with JQuery .load method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, load

With most caching problems just adding a timestamp/random number to a url will cause the loading to be refreshed. However, when using this approach with JQuery `.load` method it doesn't work. Also, using the `$.ajaxSetup({ cache:false });` doesn't work. I need to load a partial page which the .load method provides. Any ideas on how to force `.load` to reload with updated content (`cache: false`)?

The page that I am loading is a webpage that is generated by a cgi script that includes php jpgraph plots. The plots were not being refreshed when the .load method was called. As a last resort; I added the timestamp to the cgi script url that calls the php jpgraph plots. And this seems to have worked in forcing the image plots to be regenerated. I don't know if this is the best solution, but so far this seems to be working.

Comment: does jQuery.ajax() work with cache:false set?  How have you verified it isn't working?  Do you have a breakpoint in the server code.  I have found some cases where I thought it didn't hit the server but it really just hit the wrong MVC route and therefore missed by breakpoint.

Comment: *"Also, using the $.ajaxSetup({ cache:false }); doesn't work"* doesn't work, or can't use because it affects other things. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

As a test, try manually adding a new timestamp to the request url.  All the `Cache:false` option does in the `jQuery.Ajax` method is generate the _timestamp value and append it to your url querystring.

Also verify your MVC routes are setup correctly and that you are hitting the server code that you meant to hit.